# Could not connect to repo.nordvpn.com:443 (10.10.34.35), connection timed out

Tags: 18.04, apt, updates

I'm on Ubuntu  18.04. When I run `sudo apt update`, the terminal stocks in `0% [Connecting to repo.nordvpn.com (10.10.34.35)]` line.

After a few seconds it throws this error:

```
 Err:12 https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease   
 Could not connect to repo.nordvpn.com:443 (10.10.34.35), connection timed out
 Reading package lists... Done
```

I know that the repository is down.
What are my alternatives?

Comment: What instructions are you using to install nordvpn? Did you try to install .deb package from [here](https://nordvpn.com/download/linux/)?

Comment: If the repository is down then you can probably look into `/etc/apt/` folder, find the specific file, open it and comment the link ( by putting the `#` ). This will stop apt accessing that link.

Comment: @kashish: I installed Docker. As it's instructions says, I should run `sudo apt update` I wonder if it is necessary? It may be worth mentioning that I am located in IRAN which is highly banned both from local ISPs or from foreigner sites.

Comment: @AaryanBHAGAT how to find it is in which file?

Comment: Go into the `/etc/apt` folder, write command `grep "https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian" -r *`, this will give you all the required files which have the link, you can then proceed, you can go to the manual page of grep to understand the command.

Comment: @AaryanBHAGAT found them, they are in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. there are two files: `nordvpn.list` and `nordvpn.list.save`. How to make sure that no conflict on further problems may occure after I delete them?

Comment: Like I said above, open you can open those files and comment them and save. This is not a permanent solution though, you should find the new repository etc, but this will actually work for now as this will let the `sudo apt update` command run with no errors and you can update the rest of the packages.

Answer (score 2):

Your core problem is how the IP is resolved.  For whatever reason, your system is resolving `repo.nordvpn.com` to 10.10.34.35 which is a *private internal IP address*.  Which most likely does not exist on your network and won't exist on the Internet so as such it times out.

Your system **should** be resolving `repo.nordvpn.com` to 104.17.50.74 or 104.17.49.74 - the current IPs listed in Google DNS.

We can temporarily override this by editing `/etc/hosts` with `sudo` and superuser powers, and adding the following to the end of the file:

```
104.17.49.74    repo.nordvpn.com
104.17.50.74    repo.nordvpn.com
```

... and then reboot your system and try your `apt update` again.  The reboot is necessary to make sure your system's DNS cache is flushed entirely.

However, this is a short term fix.  You should check what DNS Servers your system uses and use 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 unless you have some other reason to keep your DNS servers, and you should your `/etc/hosts` file directly to make sure that there are no other entries for repo.nordvpn.com.

Comment: I added `104.17.49.74    repo.nordvpn.com
104.17.50.74    repo.nordvpn.com` to the end of the hosts file. after the restart, the problem remains unresolved. before that, I changed the DNS to 8.8.8.8. filtering internet never gets old in Iran! any other solution please?

Comment: @Shahriar.M If you are in Iran, then there's not much I can do to assist you.  It's likely they filter access to NordVPN intentionally, either by IP address or other mechanisms, and bypassing firewalls in coiuntries is very hard to do safely.

Answer (score 1):

At first change your **dns server** by editing `/etc/resolv.conf` to some where trusted like google `nameserver 8.8.8.8` then try to update the cache.
If you face the problem again I suggest to change your repo to somewhere outside of Iran(or any other non full-forbidden country) like US or UK, then try to update.

Comment: changing dns didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

I completely get it what were you stuck in and it's really annoying!
When the protonvpn was useless, I removed it but in the updating process, this error appeared.

First I followed [the official instruction of uninstalling](https://protonvpn.com/support/official-linux-vpn-debian/) `protonvpn`:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove protonvpn

rm -rf ~/.cache/protonvpn
rm -rf ~/.config/protonvpn
```

Then in `sources.list.d` remove all the files that `protonvpn` is in their name.

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

In my case:

```
sudo rm protonvpn-stable.list
sudo rm protonvpn-stable.list.distUpgrade
sudo rm protonvpn-stable.list.save
```

After that there was no error.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well.

I removed the `nordvpn.list` file located in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, and it worked.

However, I didn't want to continue using NordVPN at all. So you could comment out the different settings in the file if you plan to continue using it.